# Heavy use of HttpSession for data transfer within web pages

Tags: performance, jsp, servlets, web-applications, httpsession

i am developping a Medical Billing System using servlets and JSPs but not following MVC,therein for fetching data from servlets to view page i am putting so much attributes(lists and single valued both) inside HttpSession.will this affect my web application badly ?if yes ! how ? and what are the alternative ways instead of using session ?

Comment: While this link is not specific to java, I reckon it applies to all frameworks in general - must read to understand performance and scalability issues due to state management - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ff647787.aspx#scalenetchapt06_topic16

Comment: @swazza85 , i am sorry i forgot to mention that but i work on java technology and any help in context of java web applications would be great .

Comment: Keep data on the request? Cache DB data closer to the DB layer?  How *much* data are you putting in session? Do you *ever* clear it?

Comment: i am invalidating the HttpSession when user logs out . i dont to how to clear session attributes selectively ? @DaveNewton

Comment: Set the session attribute to null.